# How to check the Ice thread wait on object

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, ice

When i use jstack to check the process,i have got this log:

```
 "poolTaskThread-4" prio=10 tid=0x00007f09300ff800 nid=0x69ce in Object.wait() [0x00007f0aa5271000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at IceInternal.Outgoing.invoke(Outgoing.java:147)
- locked <0x0000000711754358> (a IceInternal.Outgoing)
at com.example.srv.slice._ContentSearchServiceDelM.searchContentsFields(_ContentSearchServiceDelM.java:188)
at com.example.srv.slice.ContentSearchServicePrxHelper.searchContentsFields(ContentSearchServicePrxHelper.java:665)
at com.example.srv.slice.ContentSearchServicePrxHelper.searchContentsFields(ContentSearchServicePrxHelper.java:629)
at com.example.srv.api.ContentSearchServiceAPI.searchContentsFields(ContentSearchServiceAPI.java:61)
at com.bbs.dao.ContentDao.getSortedContentsByNode(ContentDao.java:921)
at com.bbs.dao.ContentDao.getPublishContentListPage(ContentDao.java:613)
at com.bbs.service.ContentService.getPublishContentListPage(ContentService.java:60)
at com.example.service.impl.FindSummImpl.getArtificialContentList(FindSummImpl.java:227)
at com.example.service.impl.FindSummImpl.sortList(FindSummImpl.java:316)
at com.example.service.impl.MatcherImpl$PluginTask.dosortlist(MatcherImpl.java:654)
at com.example.service.impl.MatcherImpl$PluginTask.getPluginContentByQuery(MatcherImpl.java:720)
at com.example.service.impl.MatcherImpl$PluginTask.call(MatcherImpl.java:589)
at com.example.service.impl.MatcherImpl$PluginTask.call(MatcherImpl.java:472)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and have many others like this.First i think this is because of the ice connection timeout setting problem ,because i find the Outgoing.java in line 147 is like this:

```
       int timeout = connection.timeout();
                while(_state == StateInProgress && !timedOut)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(timeout >= 0)
                        {
                            wait(timeout);

                            if(_state == StateInProgress)
                            {
                                timedOut = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }

            if(timedOut)
            {
                //
                // Must be called outside the synchronization of
                // this object
                //
                connection.exception(new Ice.TimeoutException());

                //
                // We must wait until the exception set above has
                // propagated to this Outgoing object.
                //
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    while(_state == StateInProgress)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            wait(); //147 line
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

so i have add the paras Ice.Override.Connection=200000,but the problem appeared sooner,what should i do about the ice thread~~

Answer (score 0):

The Ice has a paramters is called Ice.CacheMessageBuffer,you can setting this

```
Ice.CacheMessageBuffers=0
```

this will not call the directbuffer , you can try it ,it will improve the JVM GC .